# how to use SymbolicC++ in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, symbolic-math

that's my question simply. i have tried to compile use it but it's not compiling. it 's not finding #include  and i have NDK 8d . and I also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722190 and i applied . all the options of APP_STL.. this is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := net_superlinux_generalengineeringpaid_MechanicalShearForce.c
LOCAL_MODULE := net_superlinux_generalengineeringpaid_MechanicalShearForce
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and this is my Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_ABI := all
```

so i don't know what to do.

all i need to know is how to use Symbolicc++ in my android project. 
Symja as an alternative option is making me Java heap errors.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the tarball with just headers?

- You could then add the headers to `LOCAL_HEADERS += <path_to_include_dir>` in an `Android.mk` file
- or on the command-line `g++ ... -I <path_to_include_dir> ...`
- there is also a `CPP_FLAGS` environment variable that may affect where the compiler searches for headers as well.

Someone correct me of I am wrong. Hope that helps, good luck!

Peace